# iPhone app for Joomla website?

Tags: iphone, interface, joomla

I am trying to create an app that will display articles from an online newspaper using Joomla for my school, but I have not been able to find any api to be able to send the articles to an iPhone. Is it possible to have an app that downloads information from a Joomla website for the user to read?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use any RSS reader app to pull articles from a Joomla site for reading on an iPhone. No code required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something more than reading a RSS feed from Joomla for a category of Articles then the first place to look would be the [Joomla! Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org).

If you can't find what you need you could pretty easily make a component that returns articles as a JSON structure you could then parse.

If you want more than that eg. Push notifications you will probably have to write a Joomla extension to send notifications to the servers as articles are added.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help! I think that this is what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

we released recently an updated version of our XML-RPC plugin to access to Joomla. It works also for Joomla 1.5/1.6/1.7/2.5. Its GPL and open source. You can find it in our knowledge base : [xapp-studio.com/kb](http://xapp-studio.com/kb). Oh, its also converting your Joomla site into a real iPhone app.

The xml-rpc plugin for Joomla supports also JEvents and quite a few others.

Comment: update : we've added a more easy going and complete solution, you will be amazed.